# App.config for Xunit

Tags: c#, xunit.net

I'm writing some [xUnit](http://xunit.codeplex.com/) tests for some helper classes that relies on some configuration settings, usually stored in App.config or Web.config of the executing project.

The config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="FileNamePattern" value="\\d{8}_\\w{4:20}\.png"/>
    <!-- and the likes -->
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I'm running xUnit 1.9 with the GUI runner (xunit.gui.clr4.exe) and xUnit console runner (on the Jenkins CI server). Currently, I can "inject" these configuration values into the test environments by setting the xunit.gui.clr4.exe.config and xunit.console.exe.config files manually); however, this is tedious and error-prone.

I could also mock these configuration settings in a fixture. But using the same fixture across 10 different files is rather repetitive.

Is there a better way to mock these configuration settings with xUnit, such as providing a App.config file for the test project?

Comment: I would create an intermediate ISettings. You could load the app.config into that. Then all you would need to do is mock out the interface using a framework like Moq. I quite like to abstract away config files as much as possible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your code assumes they are in the `app.config`, then xUnit.net supports having them wired up in there by providing one (typically when the tests are in a DLL file, this means you get a  `AssemblyName.dll.config` file in the project outputs which the runner loads as the settings if it exists at load time).

Obviously no harm to use the DI principle to remove such dependencies in the first place, but I'd say don't go messing with code before you actually get it under test first.

To keep it DRY, put the app.config in a central place and add it as a link (via the arrow on the Open button in the dialog). (Yes, there's lots not to like about that - use only if you feel its the least evil approach.)

---

One thing to look out for is that changes don't get reloaded in the GUI runner unless you ask for the assembly to be reloaded.

Comment: The config works fine when I renamed it to TestNamespace.dll.config and set it to always copy to the build directory. Thanks!

Comment: @ThachMai I'd be surprised if leaving it as app.config doesnt automatically work - I personally am always suspicious of it but I've never found a case where the build system wasnt actually doign the copy/rename - turn on msbuild logging and have a look (remember it won't be picked up until you reload).

Comment: I'll try it out and get back to you next Tuesday when I have access to the source.

Comment: Indeed, App.config gets renamed to TestNamespace.dll.config automatically. Awesome :)

Answer (score 4):

*From perspective more complex projects & team work, I recommend:*

1. **separate .config** file for xUnit project (it takes advantage of independent configuration & logging for running tests)
2. **set-up** *Dependency Injection* together with *.config reading* for xUnit project alone

Our team is using this pattern of xUnit **init & dispose**:

```
    public class MyTest : IDisposable
    {
        public IServiceProvider Services { get; private set; }
        public MyProjectOptions Options { get; private set; }
        public Logger Logger { get; private set; }

        private void Configure()
        {
            // appsettings.workspace.json for custom developer configuration
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.workspace.json", optional: true)
                .Build();

            Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .WriteTo.LiterateConsole()
                .WriteTo.RollingFile("logs/{Date}-log.txt")
                .CreateLogger();

            Options = configuration.GetSection("MyProject").Get<MyProjectOptions>();

            var services = new ServiceCollection();
            services.AddSingleton<ILogger>(s => Logger);
            // other DI logic and initializations ...
            //services.AddTransient(x => ...);

            Services = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        }

        public MyTest()
        {
            Configure();

            // ... initialize data in the test database ...
            var data = Services.GetService<TestDataService>();
            data.Clean();
            data.SeedData();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            // ... clean-up data in the test database ...
            var data = Services.GetService<TestDataService>();
            data.Clean();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution for me was to name the config file `testhost.dll.config`, add it to the solution, and set its `Copy to Output Directory` setting to `Copy always`.

It has to be named `testhost.dll.config` because that's how the xUnit component that invokes my tests-project is named. It can be determined as follows:

```
string invoker = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None).FilePath;
```

For my setup, `invoker` turned out to be `testhost.dll`.