# XUnit - Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime 4.0?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, xunit, xunit.net

I have a XUnit test which calls an assembly built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the .net framework. This results in the following error

> Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the
>   runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional
>   configuration information When calling the assembly from a console app
>   adding the following to the app.config file resolves the issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Adding the above configuration to a app.config file in the assembly containing the XUnit test does not help. Adding to the TE.ProcessHost.Managed.Clr20.exe config file doesn't seem to help either.

How would I get around this error with XUnit in Visual Studio 2015? I am also using a .Net Core project.

Comment: You have to name the config file properly.  Already addressed in [this Q+A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10720198/17034).

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, as I described in my post I tried adding to the app.config file. Visual studio 2015 automatically renames the app.config file to the correct name and copies to the output directory. The post you are referring to looks like it was created in 2012 so they were probably using VS2010 or VS2012. I wouldn't assume that it behaves the same in VS2015. Has anyone solved this error with XUnit in 2015?

Comment: Just worked it out. The startup supportedRuntime configuration needs to be added to a config file named dotnet-test-xunit.exe.Config located in the project containing the XUnit tests.